# How may I write Python file at run time?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to create multiple text files in Python. These files will be created as the code runs. I was thinking to use

```
fn = date.today().isoformat() + ".log"
```

or

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> fn=ctime()+".txt"
>>> print fn
Thu Feb 18 22:21:35 2016.txt
```

so that I can get unique file names always. But experiment seems not going very fine, as I want to insert data in them dynamically, as it may come from any external source. There are some silly errors happening like follows,

```
>>> fn = date.today().isoformat() + ".log"
>>> print fn
2016-02-18.log
>>> quit()
>>> fp = open( fn, "w" )
>>> fp.write( "data" )
>>> fp.close()
>>> fr=open(fp,"r")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    fr=open(fp,"r")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

or

```
>>> fn=ctime()+".txt"
>>> print fn
Thu Feb 18 22:21:35 2016.txt
>>> line1="unanimous resolution to this effect"
>>> fp = open( fn, "w" )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    fp = open( fn, "w" )
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'Thu Feb 18 22:21:35 2016.txt'
```

I am getting stuck. But my sense is telling I may be doing some interesting error. If anyone may kindly suggest how may I address the problem or resolve the errors to solve the problem. Thanks in advance. 
I am using Python2.7.11 on Windows 10.

Comment: If you try and use a colon in a file name it does strange things. See [Windows Alternate Data Streams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105763/)

Comment: Windows doesn't allow `:` characters in filenames. As an alternative you could also use the `.name` attribute of the file object returned from a call to [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile]()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) to obtain a guaranteed unique filenames (although they won't be pretty).

Answer (score 4):

The first of your errors is probably just due to a typo, you should open the readable file by file name `fn`, not `fp` (which is a file object, not a string).

The second error appears to be due to file-name restrictions of Windows, it doesn't occur in a Linux environment.

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I am reposting the question as I posted the question slightly wrong way.

Comment: FYI, "Thu Feb 18 22:21:35 2016.txt" is a file named "Thu Feb 18 22" with a stream named "21" and stream type "35 2016.txt". The latter isn't a valid stream type, such as `$DATA` or `$INDEX_ALLOCATION`. See MSDN on [File Streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404). The default type is `$DATA`, and the default stream is anonymous, i.e. `file.ext` is equivalent to `file.ext::$DATA`. A directory can also have `$DATA` streams, but not an anonymous one; trying to create or open a directory as a regular file is equivalent to accessing `dirname::$DATA`, for which access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have ":" in file name, use this:

```
import datetime
fn = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S") + ".log"
print fn
```

gives:

```
2016-02-18 174710.log
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
fr=open(fp.name,"r")
```

instead of:

```
fr = open( fp, "r" )
```